# Hibernate - Need annotations for one to zero or one

Tags: hibernate, openjpa

I'm trying to return Admin if id not found in User table

```
select * /*both admin & user data */ 
from admin,user 
where admin.id = user.id
```

I have both Admin & User (which I use for other purposes) POJOs. I include User within Admin and use `@primarykeycolumnjoin & @onetoone (optional=false)`.

OpenJPA handles this correctly whereas Hibernate gives an NPE. Does anyone know how to do this Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but I would consider changing the model. Usually "admin" is a role assigned to a user rather than a distinct entity, allowing you to have the user play different roles in different scenarios.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private final Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}

public enum Role {
    GENERAL, ADMIN, ROOT
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have used "admin".  Replace admin with staff as I'm not looking for a role.  The generic form is I want Hibernate not to error when an entity w/in an entity cannot be found when matching ids.  Also since the inside entity is reused, I do not include any annotation mapping to outside entity.